# iOS button click event show popup

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am creating a app that will display a popup view, with button IBAction event. I have taken a view. How can I map or show the subview?

Comment: You must google about iOS development tutorials. You can do this easily.

Comment: can u give the clear information

Comment: No code. No research. Do you expect us to spoon feed the answer to you ?

Comment: in xib file I have one button, when I click on button, it could be open a popup view. In that I have to perform some actions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create View in your button action.

```
- (IBAction)BtnClicked:(id)sender {
    popView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 20, self.view.frame.size.width-20, self.view.frame.size.height-40)];
    [popView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
    [self.view addSubview: popView];
}
```

And for remove view use this code

```
[popView removeFromSuperview];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create view programmatically or load from nib and add into your view controller's view on button's click as below with required frame.

```
UIView *yourpopupviewobj=[[UIView alloc] init];
[self.view addSubview:yourpopupviewobj];
[yourpopupviewobj setFrame:CGRectMake(100,50,yourpopupviewobj.frame.size.width,yourpopupviewobj.frame.size.height]
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the above answer U can create a popover,
But when U are using it in iPhone, U have to create a category file to use a popover View,
Refer this video
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1iykxemuxbk